# Unable to run selenium pytest on gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, selenium, pytest, gitlab-ci

I have the following `.gitlab-ci` yaml with one test stage and 2 services the remote browser and the docker service.

```
image: python:3.8
stages:
  - test

variables:
  BROWSER: chrome
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2


.job_template:
  before_script:
    - apt update
    - apt install -y curl docker.io 
    - docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx
    - pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - curl http://docker
    - pytest -vs --browser=$BROWSER --local='false'

e2e:remote:chrome:
  extends: .job_template
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome
    - docker:dind
  only:
    variables:
      - $BROWSER == 'chrome'
```

On the docker service I am running an nginx server at port 80, `curl http://docker` command is returning the nginx welcome's page source code, but when it comes to pytest command with the following test

```
from pytest import raises
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def test_query_window_is_visible(remote_browser):
    remote_browser.get('http://docker')
    #query_window = remote_browser.find_element_by_name('q')
    print(remote_browser.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
    assert query_window.is_displayed()
```

I am taking the following error:

> response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{"value":{"error":"unknown
> error","message":"unknown error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED\n
> (...\n#22 0x55df1954a60c \u003Cunknown>\n#23 0x55df19563c6d
> \u003Cunknown>\n#24 0x7fd4ebddb609 \u003Cunknown>\n"}}'}

Comment: Are you using GitLab.com shared runners or self-hosted runners? If self-hosted, please provide your runner configuration. Also please include the full stack trace.

Comment: @sytech I am using shared runners

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

You should add this to the job variables `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true"`.

```yaml
variables:
  FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: "true" # Define it here if you have many e2e test jobs.  

...

e2e:remote:chrome:
  extends: .job_template
  variables:
    FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1 # you can use "true" or 1 to enable it
  services:
    - selenium/standalone-chrome
    - docker:dind
  only:
    variables:
      - $BROWSER == 'chrome'
```

#### Long answer

By default GitLab runner (Docker executors) uses [docker network links](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) to connect the services with the container running the job, creating a one-to-many relationship from the job container (called `build` by default).
You can learn more about this in the [services page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#debug-a-job-locally) in the official docs

This means that containers defined in `services` cannot access each other by default.

To enable services to connect with each other and with the `build` job you should enable the `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` feature flag. Having this feature flag enabled GitLab runner creates a docker bridge network for the job and uses it instead of links to connects the containers defined in that job (main `build` container and the `services` containers.)

You can learn more [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#connecting-services) and [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#create-a-network-for-each-job).